# Can I access other MySQL database in Python Django without having access to its models?

Tags: python, django

I have this connection to MySQL Workbench database. The thing is, the database and tables isn't made by my Django project so I don't have any access to its class models. Is there any way I can add, update or delete in the database tables?

tables: TestTable1, TestTable2, TestTable3

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'test',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '1234',
        'PORT': 3306,
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'OPTIONS': {
                    'charset': 'utf8mb4',
                    'use_unicode': True, },
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom sql directly. Have a look at:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly

Comment: will that work in datatable serverside sir?